# how to fix template does not exist in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in the Django framework. I created my project created my app and test it, it work fine till I decided to add a template. I don't know where the error is coming from because I follow what Django docs say by creating folder name templates in your app folder creating a folder with your app name and lastly creating the HTML file in the folder.

**NOTE: other routes are working fine except the template**

Please view the screenshot of my file structure and error below.

[image: File Structure]

**ERROR**

```
    TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/
 Blog/index
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
 Blog/index
Exception Location: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  C:\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Maxwell\\Desktop\\Django\\WebApp',
 'C:\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Maxwell\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sun, 23 Jan 2022 12:04:18 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Maxwell\Desktop\Django\WebApp\Blog\templates\ Blog\index (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\ Blog\index (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\ Blog\index (Source does not exist)
```

**App/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request,name):
    return HttpResponse(f'Hello {name}')

def html(request):
    return render(request,' Blog/index.html')
```

Comment: Share the relevant view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you render the template with `Blog/index`, but you need to specify the entire file name, so `Blog/index.html` and *without* a leading (or trailing) space:

```
def html(request):
    return render(request, 'Blog/index.html')
```

Comment: It's already there but still not working

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea: there is still a leading space in the template name, `'Blog/index.html'`, not `' Blog/index.html'`. But the exception clearly indicates that it was triggered *without* the `.html` extension.

Answer (score 11):

I faced this situation too, and went through most of the answers here talking about the path, and editing the 'templates' function in settings.py.
In the end, it was because I forgot to add my app to the installed apps section in the settings.py file.  I saw this in the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

Comment: I tried using directories like for app 'abc', using 'templates/abc' but didn't work. Adding the app in `installed_apps` in settings worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

if @Willem van Onsem answer didn't work

create a templates folder in the main directory 'in the same level as WebApp'
then inside it create folders for each app

in your settings.py you will find TEMPLATES option

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],#add this line
        ...
]
```

and when you want to use a template

```
return render(request,"template_folder/template_name.html")
```

Comment: The template is not written in the `templates/` directory of the root, but the `templates/` of an app, so it requires `APP_DIRS` to be `True`

Answer (score 2):

Small change from @Super sub's answer.
In your settings.py you will find TEMPLATES option and change :

> TEMPLATES = [
> {
> ...
> 'DIRS': [**BASE_DIR**], #add this line 
> ...
> ]

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while running tests in my Django project.

[image]

I have two options to fix the problem. First, I edited the views.py file and deleted the empApp directory.

[image]

Second option is to create empApp folder inside the templates directory and place the html file there.

[image]

After saving the changes, the local web server for the Django project will automatically reload, allowing you to access the expected output.

[image]